# set the dropdown value to the given ID

Tags: jquery, html

I wonder if it is possible to set an HTML dropdown menu to the option matching a given id using jquery. I need this for editing some data.

```
<td id="4" class="d" > IT Department </td>

<select id="department">
  <option value="1">Admin</option>
  <option value="2">Sales</option>
  <option value="3">HR</option>
  <option value="4">IT</option>
</select>
```

In jquery:

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    var depid = $(this).attr('id'); // get the id of the department
    $("#department").val(depid); // make the IT option of the menu selected
});
```

I hope I am well understood. any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, what's your question?

Comment: so <option value="4"... should be selected cause it is the id from the td?

Comment: i think you have to select the 4th option and set it's selected attribute to true, something like `$('#department option[value='+depid+']').prop('selected',true);` or similar, i'll give it a try and reply you xd

Comment: Just try it out... http://jsfiddle.net/CFyK4/1/

Comment: @caramba: yes, that is what i want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have invalid HTML markup, your `td` not wrap inside any `table` as well as you're missing closing `</option>` tag, change to this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="4" class="d" > 
            IT Department 
        </td>    
    </tr>
</table>

<select id="department">
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Sales</option>
    <option value="3">HR</option>
    <option value="4">IT</option>
</select>
```

then you can use:

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    var depid = $(this).attr('id'); // get the id of the department
    $("#department").val(depid); // make the IT option of the menu selected
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tL2pN/2/)**